# Efficiently sort list by sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x

Lets say i have two lists:

```
sequence = [25, 15, 20, 15, 25, 25]
l = [(25, 'banana'), 
     (25, 'apple'), 
     (25, 'pine'), 
     (20, 'soap'), 
     (15, 'rug'), 
     (15, 'cloud')]
```

I would like to sort the second list l in the order of sequence.
In the example the number 25 appears multiple times, in this case it doesn't matter which tuple is in the place as long as it has the value 25.
The lists will always be of the same length.

My current approach is this:

```
r = list(range(len(sequence)))

for i, v in enumerate(sequence):
    for e in l:
        if e[0] == v:
            r[i] = e
            l.remove(e)
print(r)
```

Possible Output:

> [(25, 'banana'),
>      (15, 'rug'), 
>      (20, 'soap'),
>      (15, 'cloud')
>      (25, 'apple'), 
>      (25, 'pine')]

Do you see a better way to do this?

Thanks for your help!

Muff

Comment: Can there be repeated tuples in `l`?

Comment: No, the names are unique. Just the numbers can be redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My idea is similar to Jean's, but I use list iterators instead of the `pop` method (which runs in O(n) if you pop from the front, but in O(1) if you pop from the end).

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> supply = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k, v in l:
...     supply[k].append(v)
... 
>>> supply_iter = {k:iter(v) for k,v in supply.items()}
>>> [(k, next(supply_iter[k])) for k in sequence]
[(25, 'banana'), (15, 'rug'), (20, 'soap'), (15, 'cloud'), (25, 'apple'), (25, 'pine')]
```

The `next` method also allows for an optional default value as the second argument (`None` would be a good choice here).

Comment: Thanks for this eloquent solution - Could you please explain this part of the  supply_iter assignment: k:iter(v) - I understand that the assignment is a dictionary comprehension but i have never used this iter object.

Comment: @Raggamuffin no problem. The line you mention builds a dictionary just like `supply`, but instead of lists all the values are `list_iterator` objects. The idea is that the iterators yield a new item each time you call `next` on them. Try `myiter = iter([1,2,3]); next(myiter); next(myiter);`

Comment: Thanks! I chose your solution because i learned the most and it seems to me to be the most efficient one.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. First create a default dictonary with number as key, and names as values of each key (as a list)

```
sequence = [25, 15, 20, 15, 25, 25]
l = [(25, 'banana'),
     (25, 'apple'),
     (25, 'pine'),
     (20, 'soap'),
     (15, 'rug'),
     (15, 'cloud')]

from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for i,n in l:
    d[i].append(n)
```

then, iterate on the sequence and remove from relevant list (matching number) using `list.pop` to remove one item at a time (there must be enough items in each list and the keys must be there, or you'll get a python exception (empty list/key error)):

```
result = [(i,d[i].pop()) for i in sequence]
print(result)
```

result:

```
[(25, 'pine'), (15, 'cloud'), (20, 'soap'), (15, 'rug'), (25, 'apple'), (25, 'banana')]
```

the order is different from the expected output, but the numbers match the names, and that's the point. If you want the same order just remove first item instead (less performant in lists, so if you have the choice, better insert & remove items in a list by the last one, it's faster):

```
result = [(i,d[i].pop(0)) for i in sequence]
```

gives:

```
[(25, 'banana'), (15, 'rug'), (20, 'soap'), (15, 'cloud'), (25, 'apple'), (25, 'pine')]
```

Comment: @JaredGoguen, yes. my answer proposes both `pop()` and `pop(0)` as long as the numbers/names match it doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: If performance is a concern for using `pop(0)`, then `collections.deque` and `popleft()` could be used instead of `list` and `pop(0)`.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to sort using key function that will remove used elements from `sequence` (this approach modifies `sequence`, so the copy should be created if `sequence` will be needed later):

```
sequence = [25, 15, 20, 15, 25, 25]
l = [(25, 'banana'), 
     (25, 'apple'), 
     (25, 'pine'), 
     (20, 'soap'), 
     (15, 'rug'), 
     (15, 'cloud')]

def key_func(_tuple):
    idx = sequence.index(_tuple[0])
    sequence[idx] = None
    return idx

l.sort(key=key_func)
```

As Jared Goguen said, if you need to preserve `sequence`, the next wrapper will help:

```
def get_key_func(sequence):
    sequence_copy = sequence[:]
    def key_func(_tuple):
        idx = sequence_copy.index(_tuple[0])
        sequence_copy[idx] = None
        return idx
    return key_func

l.sort(key=get_key_func(sequence))
```

Comment: Or `sorted(l, key=key_func)` which doesn't modify in place

Comment: You could wrap `key_func` in an outer function which takes a sequence as an argument, copies it, and returns the inner function that references the copied sequence.

Comment: Setting the list element to `None` in the sort-key is clever. However, complexity will be O(n^2 * log(n)) because `list.index` runs in O(n).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without settig up an array prior the loop and without enumerate.
I don't think it's faster but maybe easier to understand:

```
r =[]

for val in sequence:
    for key, elem in l:
        if key == val:
            temp = (val, elem)
            r.append(temp)
            l.remove(temp)
            break # break the loop thru element to avoid having 2 elements of the same "key"
print(r)
```

Comment: double loop? O(n**2) complexity and also you're removing items from `l` while iterating. not a good idea.

Comment: O(n**2) is the minimum possible? The solution with defaultdict uses O(n) to fill the supply dict and O(n) for supply_iter and again O(n) for the final array. The solution with sort + index is O(n*log(n)) + O(n). Am I right ? Moreover with the pop, the loop in l is reduced every turn. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: no problem; When you have a double loop, complexity is O(n**2). Also: when you have to put a `break` somewhere, it's most of the time because you failed to find a non-linear way of searching. And the most annoying is modifying `l` while iterating on it. comparing `key` in a loop reveals that `key` isn't really a `key` :)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach,

```
sequence = [25, 15, 20, 15, 25, 25]
list1 = [(25, 'banana'), 
     (25, 'apple'), 
     (25, 'pine'), 
     (20, 'soap'), 
     (15, 'rug'), 
     (15, 'cloud')]
     
_dict = {}

# organised duplicates into dict
for a, b in list1 :
    _dict.setdefault(a, []).append(b)

print(_dict)

index_list = []

# append based on sequence using pop to avoid duplicates 
for key in sequence:
    next_in_line = _dict[key].pop(0)
    index_list.append((key, next_in_line))
   
print(index_list)
```

gives

```
{25: ['banana', 'apple', 'pine'], 20: ['soap'], 15: ['rug', 'cloud']}
[(25, 'banana'), (15, 'rug'), (20, 'soap'), (15, 'cloud'), (25, 'apple'), (25, 'pine')]

[Program finished]
```